# How to get user inputs into python database?

Tags: python, database, shelve

1. Why the menu does not start (solved by Roman Susi)
2. Why the menu do not work as expected (error below)
3. How do I solve the error in my foo.add code?

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\phonedatabase.py", line 81, in <module>
      openphonedb()
    File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\phonedatabase.py", line 23, in openphonedb
      for entry in foo.add(name, number, showtype):
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

This error happens when adding a new user, after typing in the 'Type'

```
import shelve
import string

UNKNOWN = 0
HOME = 1
WORK = 2
FAX = 3
CELL = 4

def openphonedb():
    foo = phonedb()
    print "What would you like to do?"
    print "Add = 1, Lookup = 2, Exit = 3"
    entry = int(raw_input('>> '))
    if entry == 1 :
            namelookup = raw_input('Please enter a name: ')
            for entry in foo.lookup(namelookup):
                    print '%-40s %s (%s)' % (entry.name, entry.number, entry.showtype() )
    elif entry == 2:
            name = raw_input('Name: ')
            number = raw_input('Number: ')
            showtype = input('Type (UNKNOWN, HOME, WORK, FAX, CELL): \n>> ')
            for entry in foo.add(name, number, showtype):           
                    print '%-40s %s (%s)'% (entry.name, entry.number, entry.showtype() )
    elif entry == 3:
            print "Close Successful"
            quit
    else:
            print "Invalid."
            openphonedb()

class phoneentry:
    def __init__(self, name = 'Unknown', number = 'Unknown',
        type = UNKNOWN):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.type = type

#  create string representation
    def __repr__(self):
        return('%s:%d' % ( self.name, self.type ))

#  fuzzy compare or two items
    def __cmp__(self, that):
        this = string.lower(str(self))
        that = string.lower(that)

        if string.find(this, that) >= 0:
            return(0)
        return(cmp(this, that))

    def showtype(self):
        if self.type == UNKNOWN: return('Unknown')
        if self.type == HOME: return('Home')
        if self.type == WORK: return('Work')
        if self.type == FAX: return('Fax')
        if self.type == CELL: return('Cellular')

class phonedb:
    def __init__(self, dbname = 'phonedata'):
        self.dbname = dbname;
        self.shelve = shelve.open(self.dbname);

    def __del__(self):
        self.shelve.close()
        self.shelve = None

    def add(self, name, number, type = HOME):
        e = phoneentry(name, number, type)
        self.shelve[str(e)] = e

    def lookup(self, string):
        list = []
        for key in self.shelve.keys():
            e = self.shelve[key]
        if cmp(e, string) == 0:
            list.append(e)

        return(list)
#edit
if __name__ == '__main__':
    openphonedb()
```

Comment: What is the exact question? Strip off your unrelated code and bring your problem to the point.

Comment: you should change the title and better explain what do you mean when you write "I can't get the user input part to work": is it a compiler error or a logic error?

Comment: Logic error, I'm not good with explaining, the inputs don't work with the code and produce actual results. when trying to add a user, I get `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\phonedatabase.py", line 81, in <module> openphonedb() File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\phonedatabase.py", line 23, in openphonedb for entry in foo.add(name, number, showtype): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: I can not reproduce this error. Maybe it depends on what you typed in the menu system? I suggest you to split the question in multiple ones: [1] why the menu does not start (solved by Roman Susi) [2] why the menu do not work as expected (hopefully my answer will help you on this [3] there is an error in my foo.add code: how to solve?

Comment: TL;DR, But the shelve module is not really a DB. Try starting with the sqlite module.

Comment: FYI, my own simple UI of this type is here: http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/core/pycopia/cliutils.py

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you just forgot to call the openphonedb()?
Add to the end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    openphonedb()
```

Also, what "quit" is doing there?

Comment: Nice! overlooked an easy fix, thank you. Still throwing errors at me and I'm not sure about the quit.

Comment: for that part use "exit()" instead

Answer (score 0):

code has other issues, but with regard to the first part of the question, what about comparing entry as a string (so if an user types "a" you don't get an error)?

```
def openphonedb():
    foo = phonedb()
    print "What would you like to do?"
    print "Add = 1, Lookup = 2, Exit = 3"
    while True:  # note this
        entry = raw_input('>> ')  # removed int()
        if entry == '1' :
            namelookup = raw_input('Please enter a name: ')
            for entry in foo.lookup(namelookup):
                print '%-40s %s (%s)' % (entry.name, entry.number, entry.showtype() )
        elif entry == '2':
            name = raw_input('Name: ')
            number = raw_input('Number: ')
            showtype = input('Type (UNKNOWN, HOME, WORK, FAX, CELL): \n>> ')
            for entry in foo.add(name, number, showtype):           
                print '%-40s %s (%s)'% (entry.name, entry.number, entry.showtype() )
        elif entry == '3':
            print "Close Successful"
            exit()  # note this also
        else:
            print "Invalid."
```

Comment: for the second question you may refer to the answer kindly provided by Roman Susi

Comment: another error in the code is in the lookup function: you may not initialize "e" variable (add a e = None) just after list = []

Comment: I think the lookup function has an indentation error, so you should not add the e=None line, but instead indent the    if cmp(e, string) == 0:    list.append(e) one